# Passing variable into object method javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, closures

trying to get my head around objects, methods, closures, etc... in Javascript.

Can't see why this isn't working, some fundamental flaw in my thinking I guess. I'm expecting the val variable to be passed through to the addNote() function but it isn't. I thought that any variables declared outside of a function are available to that function, as long as they're not within another function. Is that not correct?

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
      console.log(localStorage);

      var $input = $('#input'),
          $submit = $('#submit'),
          $list = $('#list'),
          val = $input.val();

      var noteApp = {

        addNote : function(val) {
          var item = val.wrap('<li />');
          item.appendTo($list);

          clearField();
        },

        clearField : function() {
          $input.val = '';
        },

        delNote : function(note) {

        }

      };

      $submit.on('click', function(){
        noteApp.addNote();
      });

    } else {

    }
```

I'm trying to learn how the pros manage to get their code so clean, concise and modular. I figured a note app would be a perfect start, shame I got stuck at the first hurdle...

Cheers.

Comment: `addNote: function(val){...}`
Your `addNote` function expects one argument, and you're calling it with none. You need to call `noteApp.addNote(val);`

Comment: You call `addNote()`, i.e. the formal parameter `val` is provided with `undefined`. If the `addNote` would be declared as `function()`, the system would try to resolve the `val` appearing in its body by outer scopes. In your case, it would access the global variable `val`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with the code in the question

1. defining an argument named `val` and not passing an argument to the function
2. when calling `clearField()` inside the object literal it's `this.clearField()`
3. You're only getting the value once, not on every click
4. `val` is a string, it has no `wrap` method
5. `$input.val = '';` is not valid jQuery

I would clean it up like this

```
var noteApp = {
    init: function() {
        if (this.hasStorage) {
            this.elements().events();
        }
    },
    elements: function() {
        this.input  = $('#input');
        this.submit = $('#submit');
        this.list   = $('#list');
        return this;
    },
    events: function() {
        var self = this;

        this.submit.on('click', function(){
            self.addNote();
        });
    },
    hasStorage: (function() {
        return typeof(Storage) !== "undefined";
    })(),
    addNote: function() {
        this.list.append('<li>' + this.input.val() + '</li>');
        this.clearField();
        return this;
    },
    clearField: function() {
        this.input.val('');
    },
    delNote : function(note) {

    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9FNe7/1/)

Remember to call the init method

```
$(function() { noteApp.init(); });
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, exactly the answer I was looking for :) I like how you've not only answered and solved the problem, you've also given me the perfect advice on how to go about creating this kind of JS. Nothing I've read seems to teach this kind of methodology when writing JS, so I can only observe other peoples code and try and work out why they did what they did. I'm still learning the basics, this is a major help. Thank you!

Comment: Reading in to it, there's a few questions floating around my head. Do you know of any resources to learn more about writing js in the kind of way? Like I'm not sure on your use of the `this` keyword, how the init function works, why hasStorage doesn't have a () and why it's a self-invoking function, etc, etc. I could just ask but It'd be nice to learn properly from somewhere, and not take up your time :) Cheers again.

Answer (score 1):

In your call to `addNote()`, you don't pass any argument for the `val`, so it will be `undefined`:

```
noteApp.addNote();
//             ^^ nothing
```

Pass the input (seems you want the jQuery object not the string value because of your `val.wrap` call):

```
noteApp.addNote($input);
```

When you declare the `val` in the function, it is scoped to that function and will only be populated if the function call passes a value for that argument. Even if you have another variable in an upper scope with the same name `val`, they are still differentiated. Any reference to `val` in the function will refer to the local `val` not the upper scope.